# Этимология слова "превратный"

Tags: этимология

Заинтересовало происхождение слова "превратный", ничего в словарях не нашла, какие есть версии?

Answer (score 2):

Превратный ― это дословно "перевернутый", приставка ПРЕ как старославянский вариант приставки ПЕРЕ и чередование ОРО/РА в корне.

ПРЕВРАТНЫЙ, -1. Устар. Изменчивый, непостоянный (обычно о судьбе, счастье, жизни). 2. Извращающий истину, ложный, искажённый. П. смысл.

**Этимология:**
Имеет общее с глаголами **воротить, ворочать, вертеть** происхождение от одного корня (о.-слав. * **vъrt**-).

Comment: Благодарю! У меня в связи с комментариями возник вопрос о происхождении слова "ворота"  - это тоже общее с глаголами воротить, ворочать, вертеть?

Comment: Да, в словаре Черных говорится, что ворота/врата известны в др.-рус. языке с 11 века и имеют общеславянскую основу vorta  и и.-е. базу vert , как и глагол вертеть.

Answer (score -2):

Отвратный, **превратный**, извратный (последние два - в части значений) - и все прочее подобное - базируется на значении "отвращать, отворачивать (от себя)" морфа "врат"/"ворот". Отсюда же одно из значений "воротить" - в выражениях типа *"меня от него воротит"*.

Прямой семантической связи к однокоренными "превращать" или "переворачивать" не имеет, вопреки Sybilla. Аналогично - "ворота", просто морф "врат/ворот" весьма многозначный. Это слова однокоренные, но из разных значений этого корня с общим значением "что-то вращающееся, поворачивающееся, способное к повороту".
Если по-простому, то всё это родственники, но не самые близкие, так сказать "двоюродные".